# Accessing arbitrarily named files according to timestamp in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file

If there are N (N unknown) arbitrarily named jpg files in a directory (containing letters, numbers and hyphens), and the matlab code wants to access these files in a for loop: `for i=1:N` where `i=1` corresponds to the file with the earliest timestamp and `i=N` corresponds to the file with the latest timestamp. In which way can this be done?

Comment: See: [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [dir](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) function to get the list of file names of the directory into a structure array.

```
filelist = dir();
```

This structure array would have the following fields for each file:

```
name
date
bytes
isdir
datenum
```

You can sort the structure array based on the filed "datenum" and then use it for your for loop.

Follow this [link](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2010/09/17/sorting-structure-arrays-based-on-fields/) for help on sorting a structure array based on fields.
It provides two ways of the achieving the goal. The first method converts the struct to a cell while the second uses a function created by some other user directly. Here's a [link](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28573-nested-sort-of-structure-arrays/content/sortStruct.m) to download the function.

Comment: Once sorted, how to rename them according to the loop index value - i=1 (1.jpg) corresponds to the file with the earliest timestamp and i=N (N.jpg) corresponds to the file with the latest timestamp?

Comment: @user5461722 once you have sorted the struct array, you can call `movefile` inside the loop with `files(sortedIndices(i)).name` as the source and build the target name from i.

Answer (score 2):

You can navigate to your directory using `cd` command and then get full info about your directory in form of `struct` using `x=dir(cd)`. You can limit your files to be of particular extension by using `x=dir(fullfile(cd, '*.m'))`.

The date of last modification can be accessed by using `x(i).date`. But for loop, it would be more convenient to use `x(i).datenum`.